# Retrieve more than 20 results with Tumblr API

Tags: python, api, tumblr

I'm trying to retrieve more than 20 results (API limit) from the following GET request:

```
request_url = 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/tagged?tag=heroin&api_key=XXX'
tumblr_response = requests.get(request_url).json()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Unlike most other API methods that offer a `limit` and an `offset` parameter to enable paging, the [`tagged` endpoint](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#tagged-method) does not offer an `offset` parameter.

So the best bet to create fetch more results is to use the `before` parameter to specify the time of the last result you found on the page before and see if you can use it to get older values.